# Is there multiple types of transitions in ffmpeg while merging two or more videos?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I have 3 video files. I am using ffmpeg library to merge them all.

While merging them right now I am using fade In/Out transitions only.

I want to enhance that feature in my site, can I do transitions like diamond, circle and some other possible transition effects.

Here is the reference urls

http://www.mediacollege.com/video/editing/transition/types.html

http://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/fcpx-effects-demo/

http://pjnicholson.com/moviemaker2/videoeffects.html

If yes then I want url of that documentation where procedue is mentioned.

Comment: AS per my check in their official docs - there is no documentation regarding this- however have hope to get something..